# End event on indefinite animation?

Tags: javascript, animation, aframe

I am trying to increase a counter every time this animation loops:

```
<a-animation id="mainAnimation" attribute="position" from="2.5 0.5 225" to="2.5 0.5 -225" repeat="indefinite" dur="7500" easing="linear" ></a-animation>
```

The animation never 'ends' so I cannot call the animation end like I normally would like so:

```
mainAnimation.addEventListener('animationcomplete', function () {
    animationIterations++;
    console.log(animationIterations);
});
```

Is there any way to listen to when the loop repeats? Thanks.

Comment: Count the duration?

Comment: @evelution That will be the fallback, but I rather not have to manually count the duration since it could be changing.

Comment: Am I crazy or am I not seeing `<a-animation>` in the list of primitives on the [docs](https://aframe.io/docs/0.9.0/introduction/)?

Comment: @zero298 Its in the 'components' section https://aframe.io/docs/0.9.0/components/animation.html#events

Comment: @zero298 Actually it looks like <a-animation> doesn't exist anymore, although it seems to work the same way as the animation component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the `<a-animation>` element is deprecated since 0.9.0 and replaced by the `animation` [component](https://aframe.io/docs/0.9.0/components/animation.html#events).

Nonetheless, how about giving the animation one iteration, and when its done - increase the counter and start the animation again

```
mainAnimation.addEventListener('animationcomplete', (e) => {
    animationIterations++;
    console.log(animationIterations);
    mainAnimation.emit('start')
});
```

You'll need to define a `startEvent` for the animation:

```
<a-box animation="property: position; to: 1 0.5 -3; startEvents: start;
       dur: 500; loop: 1"></a-box>
```

Now on each `animationcomplete` event, just emit `start` on the entity.
Check it out in [this](https://jsfiddle.net/v5sfzgby/) fiddle.

Comment: @NotZack i've expanded a bit + added an example, let me know if its understandable :)

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you much